# On android first I am capturing cookie from webview, then removing the session cookie , then again setting the cookie

Tags: android, cookies, webview

```
CookieManager   cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance(); 
    String  cookie = cookieManager.getCookie(url);

cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();

 cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
   cookieManager.setCookie( url, cookiestring);
```

removing cookie works,
how do i set the cookie back onto webview and access logged in page again

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You must use the CookieSyncManager.  From inside your activity call:

```
cookieManager.setCookie(url, cookiestring);
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this).sync();
```